# Rails cache saved files with wrong extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have mime type defined

```
Mime::Type.register "text/html", :demo
```

and controller which looks like this:

```
  caches_page :show
  def show
    .....
    render_location
  end

  def render_location
    ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        expires_in 3.days, :public=>true
      }
      format.demo {
        headers['Content-type']  = 'text/html'
        render 'fields.html.erb', layout:nil
      }
      format.json do
        out = {
          :promo_text => 'text',
          :currencies => 'eee'
        }
        render json: out
      end
    end
  end
```

Route is set lite this:

```
get '/prefix/*place', to: 'locations#show', as: 'location', defaults: {format:'html'}
```

For some reason file in cache folder is saved with .demo extension even when I request for "prefix/some-place"

I can't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that custom extension must be defined with `register_alias` if it shares Content-type with another presentation.